# Surplus part came with my dishwasher

Tags: dishwasher

I bought a Bosch SMS50E98EU dishwasher, but after installing it, there is still a part left. It is quite flexible, 3cm wide and 60cm long (just like the dishwasher).
Where does it go?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The manuals can be downloaded by entering your product number at [this link](http://portal.bsh-partner.com/portal/loginframe.htm?PORTAL_LANGUAGE=EN&PORTAL_LAYOUTINDEX=2&PORTAL_LOGINNAME=consumer_7_2&PORTAL_PASSWORD=password&PORTAL_REGIONINDEX=7).

This part attaches to the bottom-front of the dishwasher when you install it as a built-in (see page 2, step 1-6). You remove the excess from this part by cutting it along one of the groves (see page 2, step 5). This then becomes a toe kick that should somewhat resemble the location of the toe kick along the rest of the built-in cabinets in the kitchen.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The English manual I have downloaded from the Hungarian Bosch site did not have these pictures. Thanks.